# Creating Loop to Hide Rows if Rows are Hidden on another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have created a macro that will take a value from a cell in worksheet 1 and match it to worksheet 2. If the row is hidden on worksheet 1 it hides the row on worksheet 2. I need to know how to loop it through all rows on worksheet 1 and 2. Then I need it to continue to match worksheet 1 to worksheets 3, 4 & 5. I have looked but can't seem to find anything close in the various forums.

This is what I have that works. I can post the various things I've tried but none work past the first row.

```
Sub HideRows

If ActiveSheet.Range("A10") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5") And _
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

I apologize, this is the first time I have ever posted so I am very unfamiliar with how to phrase things or what I should post.

Let me try again:

I have a Master sheet. It has text data in column A on rows 10:185. If any of those rows DO NOT have numeric data in columns B thru T I have written a macro that hides those rows. Rows 10:185 are broken up by category on 5 other worksheets. I want to be able to hide the same rows in the other worksheets that are hidden on the Master sheet. I hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the If statement to return true on whether or not the row on Active sheet if hidded you need to change

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden Then
```

This will actually return a `TRUE` or `False` You also need an `End If` for a multi-line If statement. So now your If statement would look like this:

```
Sub HideRows

If ActiveSheet.Range("A10") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5") And _ 
   ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden Then
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

So this macro only looks the value in A10 and tests whether it is equal to B5 on the second worksheet and if Row 10 is hidden on the Active sheet. If you only want to look at Cells A10 on the first and compare them with B5 on all the rest, the code below will do just that (Note: This assumes that the sheets are in order of their name:

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 5
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A10") = Sheets(i).Range("B5") And ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Sheets(i).Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

If you need to do more analysis on cells other that A10 and B5 or you need more than just Sheets 1 through 5, please update your questions so we can help further.

Comment: I apologize, this is the first time I have ever posted so I am very unfamiliar with how to phrase things or what I should post.

Comment: Let me try again: 

I have a Master sheet. It has text data in column A on rows 10:185. If any of those rows DO NOT have numeric data in columns B thru T I have written a macro that hides those rows. Rows 10:185 are broken up by category on 5 other worksheets. I want to be able to hide the same rows in the other worksheets that are hidden on the Master sheet. I hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a macro that checks each row on the master sheet, if it is hidden, then the corresponding row containing that entry on one of the other 5 sheets should also be hidden.

So, assuming the text in column A on the master sheet is now in column B on the other sheets, and assuming that the other 5 sheets are sheets(2) through sheets(6) this should do the trick:

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim x As Range

For i = 10 To 185
    'check if the row is hidden, if it isn't then no need to check the other sheets
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        'loop through each of the other sheets and look for the value in column B, if found, hide the row.
        For j = 2 To 6
            'you have to "Set" an object variable such as a range reference
            'This Finds the value passed to it in the range that this is called from (in this case the entire B column)
            Set x = Sheets(j).Columns(2).Find(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not x Is Nothing Then
                x.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Pandora, do any of these responses answer your question? If so please remember to mark it as answered and/or upvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 Versions bellow work the same way

- If values in `Sheet1.ColA` match values in `Sheet2.ColB` (`Sheet3.ColB`, etc)
- And, if row in `Sheet1` is hidden

  - It will hide (identical) rows in `Sheet2`, `3`, etc

---

.

**Version 1**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MatchAndHideRows()

    Const COL_1 = "A"   'column with text data in Sheet1 (Master Sheet)
    Const COL_2 = "B"   'column with text data in Sheets 2, 3, etc

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, arr1 As Variant, d1 As Object
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, lr2 As Long, arr2 As Variant, d2 As Object, r As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheet1    'Master Sheet (Or: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, COL_1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, COL_1), ws1.Cells(lr1, COL_1)).Formula

    Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For r = 10 To lr1    'skip Header rows
        If ws1.Rows(r).Hidden Then d1(arr1(r, 1)) = 0   'remember all hidden rows
    Next

    For Each ws2 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'iterate all sheets
        If ws1.Name <> ws2.Name Then        'except Master Sheet (Sheet1)
            lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, COL_2).End(xlUp).Row
            arr2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, COL_2), ws2.Cells(lr2, COL_2)).Formula
            For r = 5 To lr2    'skip Headers
                If d1.Exists(arr2(r, 1)) Then d2(r) = 0
            Next
            ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Hidden = False
            If d2.Count > 0 Then
                ws2.Range("A" & Join(d2.Keys, ",A")).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2**

---

```
Public Sub MatchAndHideRowsCheckRowByRow()

    Const COL_1 = "A"   'column with text data in Sheet1 (Master Sheet)
    Const COL_2 = "B"   'column with text data in Sheets 2, 3, etc

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, rng1 As Range, c1 As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, lr2 As Long, rng2 As Range, c2 As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheet1    'Master Sheet (Or: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))

    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, COL_1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(10, COL_1), ws1.Cells(lr1, COL_1)) 'skip Header rows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c1 In rng1.Cells       'iterate each cell with data in Sheet1.ColA
        If Not IsError(c1) Then     'if current cell doesn't contain an error, continue
            For Each ws2 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'iterate all sheets
                If ws1.Name <> ws2.Name Then        'except Master Sheet (Sheet1)
                    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, COL_2).End(xlUp).Row
                    Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(5, COL_2), ws2.Cells(lr2, COL_2))
                    For Each c2 In rng2.Cells   'iterate each cell in current sheet
                        If Not IsError(c2) Then
                            If c1.Value2 = c2.Value2 Then
                                c2.EntireRow.Hidden = c1.EntireRow.Hidden
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```